# Creating a slackbot using slackbots.js - is there a way to post to whichever channel bot is invited to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, slack, slack-api

I am new to creating slackbots using am slackbots.js and node.js to create my first slack app. I have this completed but my issue is that I can only seem to post to 1 single channel regardless of which the bot is invited to. Is there a way to post to whichever channel the bot is installed in or called in? The documentation did not specify(or maybe I am not looking in the correct place.)

Resources and answer are highly appreciated!

Currently posting with the code below

```
const params = {icon_emoji: ':question:'}

bot.postMessageToChannel('general', 'I Am A SlackBot', params);
```

Comment: I don't have any experience with slack bots, but I bet that the [slack event api](https://api.slack.com/events-api), specifically [channel_joined](https://api.slack.com/events/channel_joined) will do what you need :D

Comment: Yes. In according to the API your app can post in every channel your bot user has been invited to if you use the bot token for the posting. Not sure how that works exactly in `slackbot.js` though.